# Creating a new Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, project

In old version of *Eclipse* and Android SDK when I wanted develop an android app I used to open "New" and then "Android Project."

Now in the new version it changed to Android Application Project and this makes me confused. There are so many opened packages and folders. I would like to only create an android project, not android application project.

I am new and I would like it as simple as possible, something like this:

[image: Old version of New Android Project menu]

Not this (newer version of "New Android Project" menu:

[image: New version of New Android Project menu]

Answer (score 4):

The new project wizard in ADT version 20 can indeed be a bit confusing.  Suggestions:

- In the first screen it is mostly the same other than a change to dropdown lists for the version selection.
- If you don't want to see the second screen picking a launcher icon, uncheck "create custom launcher icon" on the first screen.
- On the last screen, if you want to make a project that works on older versions without the compatibility libraries (ie, make an old style project) then uncheck "create activity".
- If you do File - New - Project - Android you can get at the options for creating from a sample or existing code.  If you pick an older target you can pick an older version of the samples.

Comment: thanks but its not like that in the photo i post.......oh my God.......i dont now what must i do in my country there is no any one have any information in developing for android i cant ask any one.........im Craying right now so much every day because i confused....could you give me your mail adress please

Comment: @RazarBlade - Give it another try - worst case is you mess up, delete the project, and start over.  Enter the name information in the first three blanks, then uncheck the things I suggested.

Comment: did didnt work.....no problm thanks for answers?? but if i use older version of eclipse and sdk there will not be any problem ??

Comment: If you want that badly enough you can modify the source of the tool.  Or you can learn to do the few extra mouse clicks to make it work.

Comment: could you send me your mail please this is mine : bawar_74@yahoo.com or bawar_67@yahoo.com or  jokerxxxball@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution here:

http://droiddudes.com/2012/07/12/unable-to-create-android-project-in-eclipse-with-adt-20/

Delete Android Support Tools (version 9) from ADK.

Run App wizard again -- it will complete that it requires Version 8 -- confirm you wish to install.  Version 9 gets (re)installed.  Dialog completes.

Next time you run it there are no errors, and if you look in ADT manager it is in  there (again.)

Update:  Worked  for "test" project then failed for my new real project which has SPACE in the name -- changed the PROJECT NAME (not the app name) to remove the space and the wizard completed correctly.